# R# makes my Visual Studio 2012 go into 9% CPU usage every couple of minutes plus intense I/O

Tags: resharper

The 9% CPU usage is accompanied by an unusually high I/O Total Rate as reported by the Process Hacker. Namely in MB/s whereas all the rest are in KB/s. It has very notable effect on the user experience inside Visual Studio - it is lagging.

- Solution wide analysis is disabled.
- Huge source files (above 1MB in size) are excluded from R#
- The entire source code tree is on an SSD drive.
- One solution contains 73 projects. Another one - 115 projects.
- No such influxes in the CPU and IO utilization occur when R# is disabled.

I have browsed through the various Q/A sites on the Internet. The advices I can see there - turn off that or that feature are not acceptable to me - I want R# exactly for those features.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I did some analysis using the Sysinternals Process Monitor. First, I have captured the events during the abnormal operation (9% CPU and high I/O) and then during the normal operation. The capture format is CSV and only file system events were saved. Visual Studio did nothing visibly useful during this time, except being open with the same solution of 116 projects.

Both logs are available in https://www.dropbox.com/s/aq8660wek84uais/VS2012_R%238_ProcMon_Logs.7z?dl=0 compressed in a 7z archive.

More than that, I have dumped both logs into a Sql Server 2012 database. The 7z compressed backup of which is available here - https://www.dropbox.com/s/kgb1zg4yqx9e94y/VS2012_R%238_ProcMon_Logs_SqlServer2012.bak.7z?dl=0

The difference between the two data sets is striking. I have run a few queries, below are the results:

```
SELECT 'Bad',DATEDIFF(second, MIN(ts),MAX(ts)) 'Interval (sec)', COUNT(1) Count FROM LogFile
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Good',DATEDIFF(second, MIN(ts),MAX(ts)) 'Interval (sec)', COUNT(1) Count FROM LogFile2

(No column name)    Interval (sec)  Count
Bad                 96              45814
Good                100             2042
```

The bad session captured 22 times more file system I/O events during roughly the same time interval!

Next I wanted to see the list of files both sessions were accessing.

First the bad session:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) Count,Path FROM (
    SELECT CASE 
        WHEN Path LIKE '"C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuild%\Configuration%.cache"' THEN '"C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuildNNNN\ConfigurationNNNN.cache"' 
        WHEN Path LIKE '"C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuild%\Results%\GetTargetPath.cache"' THEN '"C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuildNNNN\ResultsNNNN\GetTargetPath.cache"'
        WHEN Path LIKE '"C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuild%\Results%\ResolveProjectReferences.cache"' THEN '"C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuildNNNN\ResultsNNNN\ResolveProjectReferences.cache"'
        WHEN Path LIKE '"C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuild%\Results%\ResolveAssemblyReferences.cache"' THEN '"C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuildNNNN\ResultsNNNN\ResolveAssemblyReferences.cache"'
        WHEN Path LIKE '"C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuild%\Results%"' THEN '"C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuildNNNN\ResultsNNNN"'
        ELSE Path END Path FROM LogFile
) data GROUP BY Path HAVING COUNT(1) > 99 ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
```

Now the results are:

```
Count Path
6718  "C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuildNNNN\ConfigurationNNNN.cache"
4704  "C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\{181573c4-a37b-468b-9c8a-cbd9a1fbf4dc}\System.Data.SQLite.dll"
4240  "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atiumdva.cap"
4095  "C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuildNNNN\ResultsNNNN"
3529  "C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuildNNNN\ResultsNNNN\GetTargetPath.cache"
1022  "C:\Users\mkharitonov"
537   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Libraries\Client"
506   "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\4.0\Microsoft.Common.Targets\ImportAfter"
444   "C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuildNNNN"
321   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v5.0\mscorlib.dll"
315   "C:\dayforce\SharpTop\UI\DynaPanel\Bin\Debug\DynaPanel.dll"
302   "C:\dayforce\SharpTop\UI\Benefits\MyBenefits\obj\Debug\MyBenefits.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache"
295   "C:\dayforce\SharpTop\UI\Payroll\PayrollManagement\obj\Debug\PayrollManagement.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache"
262   "C:\dayforce\SharpTop\UI\Benefits\BenefitsAdmin\obj\Debug\BenefitsAdmin.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache"
256   "C:\dayforce\SharpTop\UI\VacationBidding\obj\Debug\VacationBidding.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache"
252   "C:\dayforce\SharpTop\UI\ControlsEx\Bin\Debug\ControlsEx.dll"
246   "C:\dayforce\SharpTop\UI\Benefits\BenefitsManagement\obj\Debug\BenefitsManagement.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache"
234   "C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.2\SolutionCaches\_ReSharper.Main.1029040524\CACHES_FORMAT_VERSION"
208   "C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.2\SolutionCaches\_ReSharper.Main.1029040524\PersistentCaches"
189   "C:\Users"
189   "C:\dayforce\SharpTop\UI\RuleEngineDataProviderClient\Bin\Debug\RuleEngineDataProviderClient.dll"
189   "C:\dayforce\SharpTop\UI\RuleEngineClient\Bin\Debug\RuleEngineClient.dll"
162   "C:\dayforce\SharpTop\UI\RuleEngineClient\Bin\Debug\DfResources.dll"
153   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Libraries\Client\System.Windows.Controls.Data.dll"
153   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Libraries\Client\System.Windows.Controls.dll"
153   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE"
152   "C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuildNNNN\ResultsNNNN\ResolveAssemblyReferences.cache"
151   "C:\dayforce\SharpTop\UI\ClientData\ClientData.csproj"
151   "C:\dayforce\SharpTop\UI\DynaPanel\DynaPanel.csproj"
151   "C:\dayforce\SharpTop\UI\ProxyService\ProxyService.csproj"
151   "C:\dayforce\SharpTop\UI\Controls\Controls.csproj"
151   "C:\dayforce\SharpTop\UI\Utility\Utility.csproj"
150   "C:\dayforce\SharpTop\UI\Controls\Bin\Debug\Controls.dll"
150   "C:\dayforce\SharpTop\UI\ClientData\Bin\Debug\ClientData.dll"
150   "C:\dayforce\SharpTop\UI\ProxyService\Bin\Debug\ProxyService.dll"
150   "C:\dayforce\SharpTop\UI\Utility\Bin\Debug\Utility.dll"
150   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Libraries\Client\System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input.dll"
142   "C:\"
138   "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v5.0\Microsoft.Ria.Client.targets"
138   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.ServiceModel.targets"
138   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Xaml.targets"
138   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WorkflowBuildExtensions.targets"
138   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WinFx.targets"
138   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Data.Entity.targets"
138   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86\signtool.exe"
138   "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Targets"
138   "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Fakes\Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.targets"
138   "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\4.0\Microsoft.Common.props"
138   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\Rule Sets\NativeRecommendedRules.ruleset"
138   "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\TeamTest\Microsoft.TeamTest.targets"
135   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Libraries\Client\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll"
135   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Libraries\Client\System.Windows.Controls.Input.dll"
135   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Libraries\Client\System.Windows.Data.dll"
128   "C:\dayforce\SharpTop\Dependencies\Silverlight5\Toolkit\Bin"
126   "C:\dayforce\SharpTop\UI\AccrualEngineClient\Bin\Debug\AccrualEngineClient.dll"
126   "C:\dayforce\SharpTop\UI\MyReports\Bin\Debug\Dayforce.MyReports.dll"
126   "C:\dayforce\SharpTop\Dependencies\Silverlight5\Toolkit\Bin\System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.dll"
123   "C:\dayforce\SharpTop\UI\ControlsEx\ControlsEx.csproj"
122   "C:\dayforce\SharpTop\UI\AccrualEngineDataProviderClient\Bin\Debug\AccrualEngineDataProviderClient.dll"
114   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Libraries\Client\System.Xml.Serialization.dll"
105   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Libraries\Client\System.Xml.Linq.dll"
103   "C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuildNNNN\ResultsNNNN\ResolveProjectReferences.cache"
```

Now the same query for the good session without the `HAVING` filter (table LogFile2):

```
Count   Path
1344    "C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\{181573c4-a37b-468b-9c8a-cbd9a1fbf4dc}\System.Data.SQLite.dll"
306     "C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.2\SolutionCaches\_ReSharper.Main.1029040524\CACHES_FORMAT_VERSION"
272     "C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.2\SolutionCaches\_ReSharper.Main.1029040524\PersistentCaches"
69      "C:\Users\mkharitonov"
34      "C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.2\SolutionCaches\_ReSharper.Main.1029040524\PersistentCaches\*"
9       "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\Accessibility.dll"
7       "C:\Program Files (x86)"
1       "C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\AutoRecoverDat\17064.dat"
```

One can examine the data in many different ways, the last query I want to run is see how many successful writes were there. I am using the same query as before, except for the `WHERE Operation='"WriteFile"' AND Result='"SUCCESS"'` filter being added to the nested select statement. Like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) Count,Path FROM (
    SELECT CASE 
        WHEN Path LIKE '"C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuild%\Configuration%.cache"' THEN '"C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuildNNNN\ConfigurationNNNN.cache"' 
        WHEN Path LIKE '"C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuild%\Results%\GetTargetPath.cache"' THEN '"C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuildNNNN\ResultsNNNN\GetTargetPath.cache"'
        WHEN Path LIKE '"C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuild%\Results%\ResolveProjectReferences.cache"' THEN '"C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuildNNNN\ResultsNNNN\ResolveProjectReferences.cache"'
        WHEN Path LIKE '"C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuild%\Results%\ResolveAssemblyReferences.cache"' THEN '"C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuildNNNN\ResultsNNNN\ResolveAssemblyReferences.cache"'
        WHEN Path LIKE '"C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuild%\Results%"' THEN '"C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuildNNNN\ResultsNNNN"'
        ELSE Path END Path FROM LogFile WHERE Operation='"WriteFile"' AND Result='"SUCCESS"'
) data GROUP BY Path ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
```

First the bad session:

```
Count Path
3321  "C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuildNNNN\ConfigurationNNNN.cache"
98    "C:\dayforce\SharpTop\UI\Benefits\MyBenefits\obj\Debug\MyBenefits.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache"
97    "C:\dayforce\SharpTop\UI\Payroll\PayrollManagement\obj\Debug\PayrollManagement.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache"
85    "C:\dayforce\SharpTop\UI\Benefits\BenefitsAdmin\obj\Debug\BenefitsAdmin.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache"
82    "C:\dayforce\SharpTop\UI\VacationBidding\obj\Debug\VacationBidding.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache"
77    "C:\dayforce\SharpTop\UI\Benefits\BenefitsManagement\obj\Debug\BenefitsManagement.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache"
46    "C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuildNNNN\ResultsNNNN\GetTargetPath.cache"
33    "C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuildNNNN\ResultsNNNN\ResolveAssemblyReferences.cache"
15    "C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuildNNNN\ResultsNNNN\ResolveProjectReferences.cache"
```

Now the good session. Wait, there are no writes at all (failed and succeeded alike) in the good session!

I would like to emphasize, that the bad behavior is only observed when R# 8 is enabled and the solution is big enough. When I suspend R#, everything is good.

Let me know if there is anything else I can do to help the folks out there to help me.

**EDIT 2**

I/O usage is less stable, sometimes it is high, sometime it is low. But the 9% CPU are pretty stable and it is nothing for the machine, but it renders Visual Studio barely usable.

Everything returns to normal once I suspend the R#. But then, I do not have R#.

P.S.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-425890

Comment: Not being snarky or anything but this... "One solution contains 73 projects. Another one - 115 projects"

Comment: Does it have the same behavior with a 10 project solution?

Comment: What is the I/O doing? Have you looked?

Comment: @JohnSaunders - I would gladly, how?

Comment: [Sysinternals Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)

Comment: That one I did. Could not identify anything interesting, lots of system files. But I will try again.

Comment: @mxmissile - nope, nothing when the solution is small.

Comment: @mark Thank you very very very much. Months of painful frustration killing vs from task mgr every 15mns or so. You probably should answer your own question to make the link to jetbrains and the solution (updating) is more outstanding. Thanks again you are my hero (:

Comment: @pasx - here you go.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still using R# 8 and are suffering, the solution is to upgrade as advised in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-425890

Answer (score 0):

I have recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2015 and Resharper 9. The experience is much smoother and there are less hangups than with Visual Studio 2012.